# Como conseguir a referência da classe selecionada no Package Explorer do Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Estou fazendo um plugin e quando clico com o botão direito em uma classe do *Package Explorer*, o meu *handler* conseguisse a referencia da classe clicada.

Quando eu clico com o botão direito em uma classe do Package explorer abre o menu, nesse menu eu criei um nova funcao (linha), quando eu clico nela ela é tratada no handler que é uma class, e nesse handler gostaria de saber como eu faço para conseguir uma instancia(referencia) da classe que cliquei com o botão direito.

A parte da Interface esta implementada no **plugin.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?eclipse version="3.4"?>

  <plugin>
     <extension
           point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        <menuContribution
              allPopups="false"
              locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
           <command
                 commandId="br.usp.each.saeg.badua.dataflow.handler"
                 label="Dataflow Coverage"
                 style="push">
              <visibleWhen
                    checkEnabled="false">
                 <with
                       variable="activeMenuSelection">
                    <iterate
                          ifEmpty="false"
                          operator="or">
                       <adapt
                             type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit">
                       </adapt>
                    </iterate>
                 </with>
              </visibleWhen>
           </command>
        </menuContribution>
     </extension>


     <extension
           point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command
              defaultHandler="DataflowHandler"
              id="br.usp.each.saeg.badua.dataflow.handler"
              name="DataflowViewHandler">
        </command>
     </extension>

  </plugin>
```

e tenho a classe **DataflowHandler.java** que eh a *Handler*

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;

```
  import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
  import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
  import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;


  public class DataflowHandler extends AbstractHandler {

     @Override
     public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
             try {

             #codigo para conseguir a instancia da classe selecionada

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return null;
     }
  }
```

Basicamente o que eu preciso é que quando eu clicar nesse botão eu consiga uma referencia para a classe Main.java, que é a classe que eu cliquei com o botão direito do mouse.

[image: Visualizacao]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente, as possíveis variações tornam o código para obter a classe selecionada um pouco complexo. Sua seleção pode conter um ou vários arquivos, bem como conceitos mais abstratos como "Projeto" ou "Pacote" (que você descartou com o filtro); Na verdade `Main.java` é apenas um arquivo contendo código fonte. Vamos chamar isso (de maneira grosseira) de unidade de compilação (em um projeto de natureza Java). O problema é que uma unidade de compilação pode conter classes, interfaces, enums, etc.

De qualquer forma, você pode obter a seleção atual com o seguinte código:

```
// Obtem o workbench
IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
// E o serviço de seleção
ISelectionService service = window.getSelectionService();
IStructuredSelection structured = (IStructuredSelection) service.getSelection();

// Pode ser um arquivo
if (structured.getFirstElement() instanceof IFile) {
    IFile file = (IFile) structured.getFirstElement();
    // Caminho do arquivo
    IPath path = file.getLocation();
    System.out.println(path.toPortableString());
}

// E pode ser uma unidade de compilação
if (structured.getFirstElement() instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
    ICompilationUnit cu = (ICompilationUnit) structured.getFirstElement();
    System.out.println(cu.getElementName());
}

// Para seleções múltiplas use structured.getIterator()
```

A interface [ICompilationUnit](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit.html) te da maneiras de descobrir se a unidade de compilação contém classes.

Por exemplo:

```
if (cu.findPrimaryType().isClass()) {
    // Finalmente o premio
    String fullyQualifiedName = cu.findPrimaryType().getFullyQualifiedName();
```

Lembrando que uma única unidade de compilação pode ter diversos tipos além do primário - você pode estar interessado, por exemplo, em outras classes (não públicas), interfaces, anotações ou enums no corpo do arquivo, bem como classes e tipos aninhados:

```
for (IType type : cu.getTypes()) {
    // Tipos do nível superior   
}

for (IType type : cu.getAllTypes()) {
    // Tipos do nível superior e tipos aninhados  
}
```

Eu recomendo fortemente o artigo [Eclipse JDT - Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and the Java Model - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) que ensina como trabalhar com os diversos tipos do JDT - Projetos, fragmentos, pacotes, unidades de compilação, métodos e campos).

Fora do escopo da pergunta, porém mande um abraço para o pessoal da SAEG e para o Professor Chaim :).

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta Anthony, como já havia algum tempo desde que postei essa dúvida já havia conseguido trabalhar com esses ICompilationUnit, mas o artigo pode ainda ser útil pois não estou usando AST.

Hahaha pode deixar, mandarei sim.

Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem o nome da classe, você cria a instância com

```
Class.newInstance()
```

Veja na [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html).

Comment: Acho que você se confundiu a qual classe quero pegar, eu quero pegar a instancia da classe q cliquei com o botão direito e não a instancia da classe que cuida do "click"

Comment: é melhor vc postar código do seu plugin

Comment: Na verdade essa seria a primeira coisa que eu gostaria de fazer, portanto não tenho código, apenas a interface e o handler

Comment: você escreveu "nesse menu eu criei um nova funcao (linha), quando eu clico nela ela é tratada no handler que é uma class". Você pode postar este código?

Comment: editei a pergunta com o codigo